# Cassandra keyspace available in other computer

Tags: cassandra

I want to create a table (on my computer) and place it on Cassandra. How should I proceed to someone in other computer have access to that table (or Keyspace)?
Best Regards
Luis

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to configure Cassandra so it's accessible to other clients on the network.

You need to set the `rpc_address` in `cassandra.yaml` to a publicly-accessible IP. It's the IP that Cassandra uses to listen for client requests. Cheers!